# Rails dual axis using Chartkick and chart js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chart.js, chartkick

I am trying to use [Chartkick](https://chartkick.com/) with the [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) adapter and am trying to make a simple dual-axis chart but none of my settings seem to work.  I know it's just a formatting issue but I feel as though I've tried everything with no luck.

My data is this format and as you can see I've added the `yAxisID` to each dataset.

```
@consultations = [{:name=>nil,
  :data=>
   [[Fri, 01 Dec 2017, 346],
    [Mon, 01 Jan 2018, 99],
    [Thu, 01 Feb 2018, 282],
    [Thu, 01 Mar 2018, 267],
    [Sun, 01 Apr 2018, 335],
  :yAxisID=>"y"},
 {:name=>"check with spouse",
  :data=>
   [[Fri, 01 Dec 2017, 0],
    [Mon, 01 Jan 2018, 1],
    [Thu, 01 Feb 2018, 9],
    [Thu, 01 Mar 2018, 13],
    [Sun, 01 Apr 2018, 19],
  :yAxisID=>"y1"},
 {:name=>"too busy",
  :data=>
   [[Fri, 01 Dec 2017, 0],
    [Mon, 01 Jan 2018, 1],
    [Thu, 01 Feb 2018, 0],
    [Thu, 01 Mar 2018, 3],
    [Sun, 01 Apr 2018, 1],
  :yAxisID=>"y1"},
 {:name=>"made post consultation",
  :data=>
   [[Fri, 01 Dec 2017, 0],
    [Mon, 01 Jan 2018, 2],
    [Thu, 01 Feb 2018, 4],
    [Thu, 01 Mar 2018, 14],
    [Sun, 01 Apr 2018, 12],
  :yAxisID=>"y1"}
  ...
]
```

When I plot the chart, the `legend` position updates, but there is only 1 y-axis and all data is plotted against it are unchanged:

```
<%= line_chart @consultations, legend: true, library: {
    legend: { position: 'top' },
    scales: {
        y: {
            type: 'linear',
            display: true,
            position: 'left',
        },
        y1: {
            type: 'linear',
            display: true,
            position: 'right',
        }
    }
}, id: 'consult-chart', adapter: 'chartjs' %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure to pass the `scales` in the correct format. [See this example of using Axis IDs in the docs.](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#axis-id)
I.e. `scales` needs to contain a `yAxes` field with an array of the axis objects and each axis object has an `id` field that matches one of the IDs from your datasets.

So, you should change your code to something like this:

```rb
<%= line_chart @consultations, legend: true, library: {
    legend: { position: 'top' },
    scales: {
        yAxes: [
            {
                id: 'y',
                type: 'linear',
                display: true,
                position: 'left',
            },
            {
                id: 'y1',
                type: 'linear',
                display: true,
                position: 'right',
            }
        ]
    }
}, id: 'consult-chart', adapter: 'chartjs' %>
```